# Flutter || Update appBar in different widget/view

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

i'm quite new to flutter and i have a big question.
I have a HomePageView with a BottomNavigationBar and a PageView with a controller to switch 4 different views.

Now, at start i was cheating because i was nesting into the Scaffold of HomePageView, others Scaffold, one for each of 4 views. So i had one general appBar (the HomePageView one), and other one appBar, different for each view, that i was using for varying things, like multiselection, change title, action, ecc.

I read that i shouldn't do it in this way, that it should be at maximum oneScaffold per view and i should avoid nested Scaffold in the same "screen".

### So, the question is, how should i do it?

I want a single appbar shared between all the views, but most important i'd like to have control on that appbar because i need to change title, and actions based on user input.

I read that i could use a callback function, but i don't like it so much because i find it like a patch instead of a properly solution, and even more, i don't think that then the appbar can give update to the view.

For example, in multiselection in a listView of a view, when i select 2 items, the appbar should show a button for delete these items.

With callback function i can change the appbar but then how the appbar can tell the view to delete the items? In that case i should save the presenter used by the view to call it then, but i find it very rough for a properly solution.

I'm not posting code because i don't think it could help to explain my question, but if you need i'll post it without problem.

Edit:

Seems like it's a flutter problem as shown here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36461, am i right or am I missing something? And in that case how would you solve this?

Comment: I am not exactly sure if I understand correctly, but to me, it seems like you want to create a "universal" AppBar widget that handles everything. It does not sound good to me - everything would be coupled and adding new views would complicate it dramatically. Instead, I'd split AppBar parts and then use them to compose specific app bar widgets for each screen.

Comment: Well, i have others views, each one with their own appbar. But in this case that there is a HomeView that allows you to switch between others 4 widget/views, seems to be the right thing to do it, reading on web (because they're both on the same screen, HomeView and child widget). How'd you split AppBar parts, or how would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood, you want to create a reusable but configurable appBar for your app, and that is way easier than whatever you might be thinking.

You can simply create a method that returns a widget, and has optional widget parameters.

Those parameters can be defined depending on your needs.

Here is an example:

```
Widget myMethod( String title, Color? bgColor, Widget? button,...){
    return AppBar( /* your custom Appbar*/ );
}
```

Callbacks are useful when the widget you are trying to create as an associated action, usually a `Save` or a `Rollback`, or a **Go back to the screen X**. 
In your example, I don't see the need for a callback, since you can literally put those actions inside a button, and just pass the button as an argument to the function.

Comment: But for doing this, every inner view should be a Scaffold, and it would be a nested Scaffold (which is bad practice for what i read).

Comment: You want to create a custom Appbar, so where is the issue with making this an inner widget?  I actually do this on my projects and it works great. 
AppBar is for a Scaffold, as a BoxDecoration is for the `decoration` property of a Container, and many other...

Comment: The problem is that i already have a Scaffold with a BottomNavigationBar and a PageView. The solution that you're suggesting would cause putting a custom appBar on every inner view, but to do that, every inner view should be a Scaffold. And (for what i've read) you shouldn't use a Scaffold nested into another Scaffold. Also, you wouldn't have a  fixed appbar that changes content based on inner view, but mobiles appbars on every view. In the end for now, i ve nested Scaffold into the first one and put an appbar on each, but it isn't actually what i want. Sorry if i'm not clear....

Comment: For my idea, you don't need to nest Scaffolds. 
Instead of returning an AppBar, you can return a Widget, and then you can use it whenever you want, without nesting unnecessary components. Instead of an AppBar, you can return a Container, or anything else. The usefulness of this method is to reuse the function call, not to make the hierarchy harder.